# SQL Find Count of Records by Day and By User

Tags: sql, count, where-clause, having-clause, datepart

I am trying to find the count of days listed by person where they have over 100 records in the recordings table. It is having a problem with the having clause, but I am not sure how else to distinguish the counts by person. There is also a problem with the where clause, I also tried putting "where Count(Recordings.ID) > 100" and that did not work either. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Person.FirstName,
       Person.LastName,
       Count(Recordings.ID) AS DAYS_ABOVE_100
FROM   Recordings
JOIN   Person ON Recordings.PersonID=Person.ID
WHERE  DAYS_ABOVE_100 > 100
AND    Created BETWEEN '2013-08-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2013-08-21 00:00:00.000'
GROUP  BY Person.FirstName,
       Person.LastName
HAVING Count(DISTINCT PersonID), Count(Distinct Datepart(day, created))
ORDER  BY DAYS_ABOVE_100 DESC
```

Example data of what I want to get:

```
First  Last    Days_Above_100
John   Doe     5
Jim    Smith   12
```

This means that for 5 of the days in the given time frame, John Doe had over 100 records each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake a readability, I would break the problem into two parts.

First, figure out how many recordings each person has for a day.  This is the query in the common table expression (the first select statement).  Then select against the common table expression to limit the rows to only those that you need.

```
with cteRecordingsByDate as
(
  SELECT Person.FirstName,
        Person.LastName,
        cast(created as date) as Whole_date,
        Count(Recordings.ID) AS Recording_COUNT
  FROM   Recordings
  JOIN   Person ON Recordings.PersonID=Person.ID
  WHERE  Created BETWEEN '2013-08-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2013-08-21 00:00:00.000'
  GROUP  BY  Person.FirstName, Person.LastName, cast(created as date)
)

select FirstName, LastName, count(*) as Days_Above_100
from cteRecordingsByDate
where Recording_COUNT > 100
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: I just needed to add "Group By FirstName, LastName" in the second to last line and it worked! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can count what you want using a subquery.  The inner query counts the number of records per day.  The outer subquery then counts the number of days that exceed 100 (and adds in the person information as well):

```
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName,
       count(*) as DaysOver100
FROM (select PersonId, cast(Created as Date) as thedate, count(*) as NumRecordings
      from Recordings r
      where Created BETWEEN '2013-08-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2013-08-21 00:00:00.000'
     ) r join
     Person p
     ON r.PersonID = p.ID
WHERE r.NumRecordings > 100
GROUP BY p.FirstName, p.LastName;
```

This uses SQL Server syntax for the conversion from `datetime` to `date`.  In other databases you might use `trunc(created)` or `date(created)` to extract the date from a datetime.

Comment: I believe he needs the `HAVING` clause to isolate days in which people have over 100 entries in the Recordings table.

Comment: @GoatCO . . . Click.  I got it.  There description in the text and the query did not seem to describe the same data structure.  I totally revised the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
 SELECT SUBQUERY.FirstName,
        SUBQUERY.LastName,
        Count(*) AS DAYS_ABOVE_100
 FROM
 (
     SELECT Person.FirstName,
            Person.LastName,
            Count(Recordings.ID) AS COUNT_RECORDINGS
     FROM   Recordings
     JOIN   Person ON Recordings.PersonID=Person.ID
     WHERE  Created BETWEEN '2013-08-01 00:00:00.000' AND 
                            '2013-08-21 00:00:00.000'
     GROUP  BY Person.FirstName,
               Person.LastName,
               Created 
     HAVING Count(Recordings.ID) > 100
 )SUBQUERY
 GROUP  BY SUBQUERY.FirstName,
           SUBQUERY.LastName
 ORDER  BY Count(*) DESC
```

Think that the Having clause works like a Where clause, but one that accept aggregates, like sum ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)). Your query had some errors,namely :

- An aggregate in the **WHERE** clause, but the Where clause do not accept aggregates.
- You were refering to the aggregate "Count(Recordings.ID)" by it alias "DAYS_ABOVE_100" in the **ORDER BY** clause. You cannot access a column by its alias inside the same select where you defined that alias. Columns can only be accessed by their alias from outside the query, like  in Charles's answer.

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I didn't noticed the "by day" part, edited the query. Added *created* column to **GROUP BY** clause to obtain total records per day, then wrapped it in another query to count the results, grouping again by FirstName and Lastname.

Comment: This only gives me the total records for each person for the entire time frame

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after:

```
SELECT p.FirstName,
       p.LastName,
       COUNT(*) AS DAYS_ABOVE_100
FROM   (SELECT PersonID, Created, COUNT(*)
        FROM Recordings
        GROUP BY ID,Created
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 100
        )r
JOIN   Person p
  ON r.PersonID = p.ID
WHERE  Created BETWEEN '2013-08-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2013-08-21 00:00:00.000'
GROUP  BY p.FirstName,
          p.LastName
ORDER  BY DAYS_ABOVE_100 DESC
```